# segmentation fault 11 in C language pthread program

Tags: c, bash

Here is my code, I cannot find the bug for couple hours. I run it on bash, and it gives the correct fibonacci output with segmentation fault 11 at the end of the line. But when I use Xcode to run it, there is no such segmentation fault but with normal return 0 at the end.

Basically I create a pthread to run the function calculate and after it is done, I run the display in the main thread.

I appreciate your time.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *calculate(int n, int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            arr[i] = 1;
        else if (i > 1)
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    }
    return NULL;
}

void display(int n, const int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong argument. You need ONE positive number as argument.");
        return 1;
    }
    int number = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (number < 0)
    {
        printf("Plese enter a positive integer.");
        return 2;
    }
    else if (number == 0)
    {
        printf("0");
        return 0;
    }
    int *arr = (int*)malloc((number+1) * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 0;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_create (&thread, &attr, calculate(number, arr), NULL);
    display(number, arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try joining your thread before exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following pthread_create documentation (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Notice the arguments to the start_routine are placed in the 'arg' param - one does not call the function directly with arguments:

> The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling process.  The new thread starts execution by invoking start_routine(); arg is passed as the sole argument of start_routine().

As a final note, you should really join the thread (pthread_join) before trying to view any memory it is responsible for mutating:

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

Comment: Thank you, my question is nearly solve. The last question is how do I pass only one argument to that function i.e the int *arr? Since the format of the pthread_create function only takes a function with void * type argument.

Comment: void *calculate(void *arg) { int *arr = (int *)arg; solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: The easiest way is to make a struct, casting its address to a void pointer for 'args'. Then, in the function, cast it back to the correct struct pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Squirrels answer. You need to pass an actual function to `pthread_create`, not to call it in the argument list. Otherwise not only is the function executed in the main thread also it's return value is passed to `pthread_create`. The function returns `void*`, so it doesn't cause a compilation error.

You should define a function which takes a single pointer argument and returns void* and pass that as the 3rd argument. Then to pass the parameters, you can define a struct that can hold the required values and pass a pointer to that as the final argument to `pthread_create`.

Inside your thread function , you can cast back to the proper pointer type and read the values and use them in your thread function.

Here is a complete example showing how to wrap the multiple parameters and pass to `pthread_create`.

I just created a struct to hold the required parameters and created one to pass to `pthread_create`. In the thread function , you cast it back to the real type and read the values.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct params
{
    int n;
    int* arr;
};

void calculate(int n, int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            arr[i] = 1;
        else if (i > 1)
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    }
}

// wrapper to pass function to thread
void* calcwrap(void* data)
{
    struct params* p = (struct params*)data;
    calculate(p->n, p->arr);
    return NULL;
}

void display(int n, const int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong argument. You need ONE positive number as argument.");
        return 1;
    }
    int number = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (number < 0)
    {
        printf("Plese enter an integer.");
        return 2;
    }
    else if (number == 0)
    {
        printf("0");
        return 0;
    }
    int *arr = malloc((number+1) * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 0;

    struct params thread_params = {number, arr};
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_create (&thread, &attr, calcwrap, &thread_params);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    display(number, arr);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```